# Captcha script for PHP 4.3.X

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, php4

I have php 4 installed and I am using recaptcha for captcha, But its not so user friendly, So i am looking for any captcha script that is user friendly, easy to implement and **must be compatible with php 4.3.x.**

OR Is there any way to **customize the recaptcha** so that it becomes **user friendly** and not as complicated as now. and the **characters length should be 3 or 4 max**. I have searched many captcha's they were up to my requirements but there are not compatible with php4.

Comment: Well, you have to ask yourself why would someone be willing to create a nice implementation of CAPTCHA which (almost) nobody will use. Can't you install / update anything on that machine?

Comment: The older version of Securimage, [version 2.0.2](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/securimage-2.0.2.zip) it is compatible with PHP 4.3 and can be customized to meet your requirements of character length.  I'd recommend deleting securimage_play.php if you need to use that version.  You can use TTF or GD fonts in that version.  Hope it helps.